# Chrome packaged app storage error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-app-developer-tool

I am developing chrome packaged app, in that I am trying to store image file src

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABVYAAAMACAIAAABAXKuVAAAAAXNSR…VfbVgqaRelcVEBGsvnnbGxd3Egx8qvAVQZr7jWuhCJyuv+L/ESanfJ7fsXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

While storing it, I am getting following error in chrome app, can any one help?

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running storage.set: QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded
    at FileReader.reader.onload (chrome-extension://lfpolenffdnfgbebcneolkflhgcjifmh/javascript/MajorOp1.js:241:22)
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [Chrome API for chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)

> The maximum amount (in bytes) of data that can be stored in local
>   storage, as measured by the JSON stringification of every value plus
>   every key's length. This value will be ignored if the extension has
>   the unlimitedStorage permission. Updates that would cause this limit
>   to be exceeded fail immediately and set runtime.lastError.

So you need to specify `unlimitedStorage` permission in your manifest.json.

Please note, that it still won't work with `chrome.storage.sync`.

**Next time when you post such a question, please also put the code you try to execute.**